# Buscar lista de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Atualmente em meu sistema, estou chamando cada coluna de uma vez:

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT group_id FROM login WHERE userid = '$userid'");
$exibe2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2);
$_SESSION['group_id']=$exibe2['group_id'];
```

E no arquivo estou chamando assim:

```
echo ' '.$_SESSION['group_id'].' ';
```

Funciona perfeitamente para somente um dado de uma tabela, mas caso eu queria fazer algo do tipo:

```
$sql4 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT account_id,userid,sex,email,group_id,last_ip,unban_time,diasvip,cash2 FROM login ORDER BY account_id WHERE userid = '$userid'");
$exibe4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql4);
```

No caso eu quero buscar várias colunas que possuem vários resultados cada uma, como eu faço para chamar este resultado no PHP?

Comment: Qual a dificuldade de fazer a mesma coisa?

Comment: No caso eu estava chamando assim: `$_SESSION['group_id']=$exibe2['group_id'];` agora eu chamaria assim? `$_SESSION['verdados']=$exibe4;` porque não é só mais uma coluna que eu quero pegar, são varias. E se eu uso do jeito que eu postei, retorna o seguinte erro: `Notice: Array to string conversion in`

Comment: Mas você está querendo fazer uma coisa diferente, se você quer várias colunas, use várias colunas, basta reproduzir o que você fez com uma nas outras. Não é para inventar um jeito novo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não gosto deste jeito de trabalhar com resultados mas se é o que você escolheu vamos por ele. Para as demais colunas basta seguir a mesma técnica usada para uma coluna:

```
$sql4 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT account_id, userid, sex, email, group_id, last_ip, unban_time, diasvip, cash2 FROM login ORDER BY account_id WHERE userid = '$userid'");
$exibe4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql4);
$_SESSION['account_id'] = $exibe4['account_id'];
$_SESSION['userid'] = $exibe4['userid'];
$_SESSION['sex'] = $exibe4['sex'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $exibe4['email'];
$_SESSION['group_id'] = $exibe4['group_id'];
$_SESSION['last_ip'] = $exibe4['last_ip'];
$_SESSION['unban_time'] = $exibe4['unban_time'];
$_SESSION['diasvip'] = $exibe4['diasvip'];
$_SESSION['cash2'] = $exibe4['cash2'];
```

Eu acho possível que pode ser jogado direto em `$_SESSION` sem usar `$exibe4` mas como não posso testar não vou garantir.

Também acho que poderia guardar todo o `$exibe4` em `$_SESSION` e depois ler cada elemento. Mas novamente não vou garantir por não poder testar. Seria mais ou menos isto:

```
$_SESSION['verdados'] = $exibe4;
```

e o uso seria:

```
echo ' '.$_SESSION['verdados']['account_id'].' ';
// ... continua aqui para todas as colunas
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/GenericSession.php).

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento muito vasto então foi o jeito que eu achei :/ Tentei fazer do 1 jeito que você explicou, ele até retornou as colunas, porém só da primeira linha. Eu tirei WHERE userid = '$userid' para ver se retornava o resto porém sem sucesso.

Comment: O exemplo que você usou na pergunta só retorna uma linha também. A solução que eu dei está de acordo com o que você postou na pergunta. Se você tem um outro problema que deseja resolver você pode abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: Ta mas no caso `SELECT account_id, userid, sex, email, group_id, last_ip, unban_time, diasvip, cash2 FROM login ORDER BY account_id` ele não deveria retornar TODAS as linhas de account_id, userid, sex... e ordenar pela account_id ??

Comment: Sim, mas esta *query* é diferente da que você usou. Se vai realmente retornar várias linhas e jogar em uma `$SESSION`, eu vou dizer para não fazer isto. Tem que achar outra solução, por isto o problema e a solução é completamente outra. Já aviso para abrir outra pergunta pedindo uma solução e nem fale em uso de `$_SESSION`, deixe em aberto.

Answer (score 1):

Se pretendes recolher todas as colunas e passar os seus valores para a sessão, podes fazer uso do [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$sql4 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT account_id,userid,sex,email,group_id,last_ip,unban_time,diasvip,cash2 FROM login ORDER BY account_id WHERE userid = '$userid'");
$exibe4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql4);

foreach ($exibe4 as $k => $v) {
    $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
}
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Fb2oun).

Comment: No caso eu chamaria no arquivo somente $v ou $_SESSION[$k] ?

Comment: Se analisares a demonstração, podes verificar que o `$k` é o nome da chave que vem da base de dados e o `$v` o seu valor... o teu array de sessão ficará igual ao array que vem da base de dados. Se tiveres dúvidas, deixa um comentário que mais tarde aprimoro a resposta.